# jQuery dynamic onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add dynamic onclick to a row this way,

```
function addStudent(data) {
    var row = $('#students').append('<tr itemId="' + data.ID + '" ></tr>');
    row.on("click", function () {
        console.log(data.ID);  // THIS IS JUST FOR TESTING
        //loadStudent(data);
    });
}
```

why in console I am getting all ids when click on just one row ?

**Issue ?**

on click on any row I get all data or student ids in console for this example.

**Edit**

Please note data.ID is here for example as you can see I commented out real code where I am passing full object to another method.

Comment: event delegation is the answer

Comment: Please don't forget the point that I want to pass data to another function

Comment: A side note, use `data-*` attributes, `data-itemId` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To attach the click event to the `<tr>`, you need to write it like this:

```
$('<tr itemId="' + data.ID + '" ></tr>').appendTo('#students').on("click", function () {
        console.log(data.ID);
        //loadStudent(data);
    });
```

This will create the `<tr>` append it to `#students` and then attach the on click event to the newly created `<tr>`

If you want to pass data to the event, you can do it like this:

```
$('<tr itemId="' + data.ID + '" ></tr>').appendTo('#students').on("click", { value: data }, function () {            
        var theData = event.data.value;
        console.log(theData.ID);
        //loadStudent(theData);
    });
```

For more info on this concept, see [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

Answer (score 0):

> why in console I am getting all ids when click on just one row ?

Because each time you call `addStudent`, you are binding an additional click handler inside the function.

Bind the click handler outside the function with *delegation*.

```
$('#students').on('click', 'tr', function(){
     console.log(data.ID);
        //loadStudent(data);
    });
```